# JSON api with Javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to build a indian rail api  like "http://api.railwayapi.com/v2/pnr-status/pnr/1234567890/apikey/myapikey/". this is giving me json output like this-

```
    {
     "response_code": 200,
     "debit": 3,
     "pnr": "1234567890",
     "doj": "25-6-2017",
     "total_passengers": 3,
     "chart_prepared": true,
     "from_station": {
     "name": "Kopargaon",
     "code": "KPG"
    },
     "to_station": {
     "name": "Hazrat Nizamuddin",
     "code": "NZM"
    },
     "boarding_point": {
     "name": "Kopargaon",
     "code": "KPG"
    },
     "reservation_upto": {
     "name": "Hazrat Nizamuddin",
     "code": "NZM"
    },
     "train": {
     "name": "GOA EXPRESS",
     "number": "12779"
    },
     "journey_class": {
     "name": "SLEEPER CLASS",
     "code": "SL"
    },
     "passengers": [
    {
     "no": 1,
     "coach_position": 0,
     "current_status": "RLWL/11",
     "booking_status": "RLWL/39/GN"
    },
    {
     "no": 2,
     "coach_position": 0,
     "current_status": "RLWL/12",
     "booking_status": "RLWL/40/GN"
    },
    {
     "no": 3,
     "coach_position": 0,
     "current_status": "RLWL/13",
     "booking_status": "RLWL/41/GN"
     }
    ]
    }
```

Now how can i parse these valuses by javascript or php to show them in my website in a TABLE? I am new to this. kindly help me-

Comment: Have you googled about it? there are lots of tutorials about this.

Comment: *how can i parse these valuses by javascript* - use `JSON.parse` *or php* use `json_decode` ... *to show them in my website in a TABLE?* create a table from the data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //step1
$cSession = curl_init(); 
//step2
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.railwayapi.com/v2/pnr-status/pnr/1234567890/apikey/myapikey");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
//step3
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
//step4
curl_close($cSession);
//step5
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use PHP:
Then use json_decode() function it will convert json to array eg.

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_data);
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
//show from and to station
echo $data->from_station->name;
echo $data->to_station->name;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but how can i get data from the url "http://api.railwayapi.com/v2/pnr-status/pnr/1234567890/apikey/" in your code directly?

Comment: By using CURL you can get the data.

Comment: Pass `true` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to ask it to return arrays, not objects. It's easier to work with arrays and PHP provides [a lot of functions to process them](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).